# Can I buy Halo Combat Evolved online for a 360?

Tags: xbox-360, halo-combat-evolved

I have an Xbox 360. I'd love to play the original Halo. I can find the discs for all the other Halos, and I can find the CASE for the original Halo, but I can't find the disc.

Is it possible to buy the original Halo online and download it directly to the 360 and play it? Or do I have to buy a physical disc?

---

FWIW Xbox Live (and/or whatever the online service the Xbox offers) confuses me. On the Xbox 360 I searched for Halo and I FOUND "Halo: Combat Evolved" plus extras...but no screen or button where I could purchase or download it, or see a price. If it is available for online purchase+download, I would appreciate details on the steps needed to do so.

Comment: A re-release of the game for 360 called [Halo: Combat Evolved Anniversary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo:_Combat_Evolved_Anniversary) exists. The [Wiki page for the original game](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo:_Combat_Evolved) also says it was released as a downloadable game for the 360, though in not sure of the steps you need to take to download it.  It's possible it no longer available on the market for download and is just there for reference.

Comment: I should note that the re-release offers updated and the original graphics so you can play it in all of its original glory.

Comment: @TimmyJim This is, I believe, what I found when I searched the store for games, but I saw no way to actually buy it. No price was listed on any screen that I could see.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 360 marketplace anymore so I couldn't tell you how to. I would say it would be fairly straightforward to download it, but since it doesn't appear there is a way, I'm banking on that it's not there anymore. If you get/have an Xbox One, the Master Chief Collection has this game as well as halo 2, 3, and 4 (and I think ODST, but that might be extra).

Comment: @TimmyJim The original 2007 digital re-release is still available on the Xbox Marketplace for 360.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a digital download version of Halo: Combat Evolved for Xbox 360 released in 2007.  I own it, and you can still purchase it.

[Here it is on the Marketplace](https://marketplace.xbox.com/en-us/Product/Halo-Combat-Evolved/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8024d53084c).  You want the actual game ($9.99), and not the Theme or Picture Pack.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why I can find it on the store but not figure out how to purchase it. Perhaps I'm not signed in properly, or my account doesn't have a proper CC associated, or my account is locked from purchasing or something. With your answer in mind, I'll persevere, now that I know that the cause is not hopeless.